# How to create a user without a password in Catalina, Ventura and later?

Tags: password

I have a new computer and want to create a guest user whom's all data is not deleted every time it logs out. On my old computer I just created a user called guest and left the password field empty but now, in Catalina, the password field is required (although my other computer's guest account remain passwordless even after upgrading to Catalina).

Any workarounds? Or can the password somehow be deleted after the account is created?

Please note: the built-in guest account functionality doesn't fit my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running **macOS Catalina 10.15.2** and **guest** is a reserved **name**, so you cannot use it.

I also just created a new **standard** account **without** a *password*. Just didn't put in a *password* and followed through with the prompts appropriately.

Note: My **Mac** is not encrypted and does not have the **T2** chip. Either or both of these may require a *password* to be assigned.

One thing you can try is in **Terminal** use the `passwd` *command* to change the *password* to a blank *password*. This worked for me on my system, however keep in mind the note above.

Comment: On my computer a password is required, and it must be at least 4 characters, when I create a new user.

Comment: @hensti, Is this your own personal Mac or one belonging to the company you work for? Which model and year Mac do you have?

Comment: It is private and I bought it new a couple of days ago.

Comment: @hensti, Which model and year Mac do you have?

Comment: Do you have Filevault enabled?  If so, it may be requiring a password if it is trying to automatically add the new user to the list of users authorized to unlock the disk.

Comment: @user3439894 AIr 13" 2019, MBP 16".

Comment: @user128998 FileVault is enabled by default. Yes, on my two other computers, the guest user csnnot login after a restart. First one of my other users need to login to unlock FileVault.

Comment: My guess is, that with Filevault enabled, all new users get automatically added to its “enabled” list. If so, then you could try adding the new user (with a password), going to System Preferences->Security & Preferences->Filevault and removing the new user from the “Enabled Users” list.  Then login as the new user and change their password to be empty.

Comment: @user128998 Can't find that setting in Ventura. Do you know if it has changed name or so?